# Organizing data with 3 arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, matrix

I am making a program that automates data messaging.

I have an Excel sheet that has a Name column, Type Column, and Value Column.

It looks like this:

```
Name   Type   Value
Sam    A      32
Ben    B      65
Sam    B      213
max    B      23
max    C      24
max    C      12
Ben    C      45
```

This data is not real, but it is similar to what I am working with.

**Note**: some of the names do not have certain types.

I have loaded the data in 3 arrays `arrName[]`, `arrType[]`, and `arrValue[]`

I wish to make the data look like this with a 3D array `arrPro[name, type, value]`. All the values of the same type should belong to the same name and all the values should be added up together to form a total value.

Comment: Load the data in data table/data set. If you don't know how to transfer excel to DataSet I can provide you code.

Comment: i have already loaded the data into 3 different arrays.
I want the data to look like
Max - A 144
    - B 344
    - C 223
Sam - A 343
    - B 23

Comment: Okay man your call, good luck. Probably someone will answer you.

Comment: In your question, what is index and what is data is not really clear.
I will suppose that you want to index the data by `Name` property.
You should use a `Dictionary<string, List<PatientData>>` where `PatientData` store `Type` and `Value`.

Comment: @Matty Could you post result which you want to get based on data which you have posted in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Load excel data directly to DataSet is the most simple method.

If you do want a 3D array, I suggest 
    `Tuple<string, string, int>` as the data holder for each row.

and 
    `List<Tuple<string, string, int>>` will hold all your data.

Answer (score 0):

This structure might hold your data

```
public class MyTypes
    {
        public string TypeName;
        public List<NamesValues> Names;
    }


    public class NamesValues
    {
        public string Name;
        public List<int> Values;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Dictionary.

```
public Enum EType
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public class PatientData
{
    public EType Type { get; set; }
    public int Value {get; set; }
}

public class PatientManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<String, List<PatientData>> _patients = new Dictionary<String, List<PatientData>>();


    public void AddPatientData(string name, EType type, int value)
    {
            var patientData = new PatientData
                {
                    Type = type,
                    Value = value
                };
            List<PatientData> patientDatas;
            if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out patientDatas))
            {
                patientDatas = new List<PatientData>();
                dictionary.Add(key, patientDatas);
            }
            _patientDatas.Add(patientData);
    }

    public void LoadData(string[] names, EType[] types, int[] values)
    {
        var iMax = Math.Min(names.Length, Math.Min(type.Length, values.Length));
        for (var i = 0; i < iMax; i++)
        {
            AddPatientData(names[i], types[i], values[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not **simplier and cleaner** to store your data in some `List<YourObject>` for example:

```
public class YourObject {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type{ get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

and then count what you want with linq (more less):

```
List<YourObject> yourObject = "your logic goes here (with whole data)";
List<YourObject> result = from s in yourObject 
    group s by new { s.Name, s. Type) into r
    select new YourObject { Name = r.Name, Type = r.Type, Value = r.Sum(s => s.Value) };
```

I'm not shure it's exactly what you're looking for (grouping type).